# How to get the coreData property and pass it to another view through navigationLink

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I want to list the coreData object and then pass the property of it to another view. But the error show that I can not get the property of coreData object for passing it to AnotherView through NavigationLink.

```
struct StartView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: User.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var users: FetchedResults<User>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.users, id: \.id) { user in
                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView(userID: user.id)) { // Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'id'
                    Text(user.name ?? "unknown name")                       // Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'name'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var userID: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("The userID is \(userID)")
    }
}
```

Comment: If User exists and those member are valid, then it might be an issue with autogenerated interfaces. Try to restart Xcode, clean-rebuild, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a work around of it.

```
struct StartView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: User.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var users: FetchedResults<User>
    @State private var userID: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.users, id: \.id) { user in
                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView(userID: userID)) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.userID = user.id!.uuidString
                    }) {
                        Text(user.name ?? "unknown name")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to push the Core Data entity directly to the next view.

Change AnotherView to accept a instance of User entity.

```
struct AnotherView: View {
    var user: User
    var body: some View {
        Text("The userID is \(user.id)")
    }
}
```

Then pass the User object to that View.

```
ForEach(self.users, id: \.id) { user in
    NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView(user: user)) { // Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'id'
        Text(user.name ?? "unknown name")                       // Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'name'
    }
}
```